# Trying to divide two numbers and not have it round the numbers that it is dividing asp.net

Tags: asp.net, numbers, division

I am trying to divide two numbers and have it not round to the nearest whole number

```
    Dim dImgRatio As Decimal = 1.566
    Dim newWidth As Decimal = 400
    Dim newHeight As Decimal = newWidth \ dImgRatio
```

It always gives me newHeith = 200 instead of 255

It is like it is rounding the dImgRatio up to 2 before it does the division.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the wrong type of operator for decimal division, it is forward slash `/` **and not** backslash `\`

```
Dim newHeight As Decimal = (newWidth / dImgRatio)
```

Backslash is used for integer division, that is why your `newWidth` is converted to integer value (rounded)

[Arithmetic Operators in Visual Basic](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b6ex274z.aspx)

> Integer division is carried out using the \ Operator (Visual Basic).
>   Integer division returns the quotient, that is, the integer that
>   represents the number of times the divisor can divide into the
>   dividend without consideration of any remainder.

**Also see:** [\ Operator (Visual Basic)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0e16fywh.aspx)

> Before performing the division, Visual Basic **attempts to convert any
>   floating-point numeric expression to Long**. If Option Strict is On, a
>   compiler error occurs. If Option Strict is Off, an OverflowException
>   is possible if the value is outside the range of the Long Data Type
>   (Visual Basic). The **conversion to Long is also subject to banker's
>   rounding**.